# Changing the datatype of one property in a struct goes over the contract size limit?

Tags: solidity, contract-design

Given this struct

```
struct Marker
{
    string Key;
    string Category;
    bool Include;
}
```

Our contract compiles within the size limit.

But changing it to

```
struct Marker
{
    bytes4 Key;
    bytes12 Category;
    bool Include;
}
```

Pushes the contract over the limit. And even more perplexing, keeping that change and trying to reduce the contract size by removing some code doesn't bring it back under the limit!

Does using bytesx instead of string have that big an effect on contract size?? Shouldn't it actually improve the contract size?

Also, what effect does importing libraries have? For example, having made that change we removed importing "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol", but this didn't help. Wouldn't the removal of an import like this have a significant effect on contract size?

Bonus question: values of type Marker are passed into the contract via

```
    Marker[] internal Markers;

    .
    .

    function setMarkers(Marker[] calldata _markers) external
    {
        delete(Markers);

        for(uint i = 0; i < _markers.length; i++)
        {
            Markers.push(_markers[i]);
        }
    }
```

Obviously this isn't as efficient as it could be for storage. We think it would be better to have the Marker struct as

```
struct Marker
{
    bytes4 Key;
    bytes12 Category;
}
```

and then have two marker arrays in storage - one for included markers and one for excluded markers. However, it's neat and efficient for our client code (C#) to use the first definition. So is there a way of defining a solidity function that takes an array of structured data without having a struct definition ... something like

```
    Marker[] internal IncludeMarkers;
    Marker[] internal ExcludeMarkers;

    .
    .

    function setMarkers((bytes4 key, bytes12 category, bool include)[] calldata _markers) external
    {
        delete(IncludeMarkers);
        delete(ExcludeMarkers);

        for(uint i = 0; i < _markers.length; i++)
        {
            if (_markers[i].include)
            {
                IncludeMarkers.push(Marker(key, category));
            }
            else
            {
                ExcludeMarkers.push(Marker(key, category));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is because the second version the struct fields are packed, so in order to use them the compiler has to generate extra code to mask and shift the values. Have you enabled the optimizations in the compiler settings? I can't comment on the rest because you haven't provided enough details, like source, solc version, or compiler settings.